# variable returns the word ARRAY in session

Tags: php, arrays

So I have two pages a form page and a send page. The first page starts a session to store an array of items into the variable `$mine` like so

```
<? php session_start(); ?>
<?php foreach($items as $itemIndex => $item): ?>
        <?php $product->load($item->getProductId()); ?>
    <tr>
        <td >
          <?php #echo $item->getItemNumber(); ?>
          <?php echo $item->getFullDisplayName(); ?>
          <?php $_SESSION['mine'] = $mine; 
            $mine [] = $item->getFullDisplayName();
          ?>
        </td>
```

Then on the second I would display the items except it only returns the word ARRAY.

```
<?php

 session_start();

// Send the email
 $to = "packytagliaferro@gmail.com";
 $name = $_POST['name'] ; 
 $from = $_POST['email'] ; 
 $phone = $_POST['phone'] ; 
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
 $headers .= "From: $from"; 
 $subject = "Pump Part Inquiry"; 
 $mine = $_SESSION['mine'];
 $flygt = $_SESSION['flygt'];

 $emailBody = "
  <html>
      <head>
        <style>
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1> Pump Inquiry</h1>
        <h3>From:".$name."<h3>
        <h3>Phone:".$phone."<h3>
        <p>Minetuff Parts:".$mine."</p>
        <p>Flygt Parts:".$flygt."</p>
      </body>
  </html>";



 $send = mail($to, $subject, $emailBody, $headers); 
    if($send) 
        {header( "Location: http://fitter.henry-griffitts.com/fitter/success.php" );} 
    else 
     {print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please review your information"; } 
 ?>
```

Comment: You can't output an array directly! ```echo $mine``` makes no sense when $mine is an array because PHP does not know how to do the output directly. You need to traverse the array (foreach) to do the output the way you want (or use an implode function)

Answer (score 1):

When you are making the `$mine` variable you are putting `[]` which is making it an array. So even though you are only putting in the `getFullDisplayName()` it is still an array with 1 value

```
['Full Display Name']
```

So when you are trying to echo out the variable it is just saying that its an array.

Try echoing `$mine[0]`

You could always just make the session variable a string instead of an array with 1 value

`SESSION['mine'] = $item.getFullDisplayName()`

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are assigning the value to $mine after you set the `$_SESSION['mine']` 
try this

```
 <?php 
         $mine [] = $item->getFullDisplayName();
         $_SESSION['mine'] = $mine; 
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's so because you are trying to output the array $mine as a string.
Here:

```
"<p>Minetuff Parts:".$mine."</p>""
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing an array into `$_SESSION["mine"]`:

```
$_SESSION['mine'] = $mine; 
$mine [] = $item->getFullDisplayName();
```

And then you are trying to add it to a string, here:

```
$emailBody = "...<p>Minetuff Parts:".$mine."</p>...";
```

PHP's default array to string convertion is to just return a string `Array`. If you want for instance a list seperated by commas do this:

```
$mineString = implode(", ", $mine);
$emailBody = "...<p>Minetuff Parts:".$mineString."</p>...";
```

Comment: I knew I had to do something with the implode function. Thanks. Worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have make the assignment `$_SESSION['mine'] = $mine;` after  like this:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php $mine = array();?>
<?php foreach($items as $itemIndex => $item): ?>
        <?php $product->load($item->getProductId()); ?>
    <tr>
        <td >
          <?php #echo $item->getItemNumber(); ?>
          <?php echo $item->getFullDisplayName(); ?>
          <?php $mine[] = $item->getFullDisplayName(); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php $_SESSION['mine'] = $mine;?>
```